# how to have NGINX serve specific directory within a path?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have an NGINX server block that is serving files from `demos.example.com` - within this folder, i have a bunch of directories, each with a `dist` folder within them. I want to make it so if i want to view my `example1` demo, i would visit `demos.example.com/example1` and it would serve its root from `/var/www/demos.example.com/example1/dist/`. I have tried using 'alias' within individual specific `location` blocks but doesn't seem to be the correct way to do this - any tips on getting my files to serve from the /dist directory of each path?

So basically, my file structure is like this

```
example1
  - /dist
    - index.html
  - /src

example2
  - /dist
    - index.html
  - /src
```

I want to be able to navigate to /example1, but have its index file served from /dist folder.

I have tried to set specific location blocks with the specific directories name and set alias/root, but even that didn't work - I preferably would like it so i could just create a new directory, build to /dist and then automatically be able to navigate to that directories name and be served /dist/index.html.

Heres my current server block

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/demos.example.com/html/demos;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name demos.example.com www.demos.example.com;

        location /example1 {
                # I had also tried 'alias' to no prevail
                root /var/www/demos.example.com/html/demos/example1/dist;
                        index index.html index.php;

                        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }





}
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: can you create an example1 directory inside /example1/dist ? If you put /example1/dist and you enter with "/example1" , it'll search for  /example1/dist/example1 . This, or set root to demos.example.com/html , and "try_files $uri/dist" so it searches for /example1/dist/index.html

Comment: `root` will not work in this situation. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details. You need to use: `alias /var/www/demos.example.com/html/demos/example1/dist;`

Comment: @RichardSmith as mentioned, i has already tried with using alias rather than root. I am still getting a 404 page when trying to visit `example.com/example1`.